# Compare 2 strings and return amount of matching letters java

Tags: java

How does one compare 2 Strings to return an int of amount matched in Java?

I have a "lottery number" which is a UUID and looks like 561637ba-06f6-4457-9787-ba65768c1b73 I would compare it to another string like 72c92628-5789-4d5c-9287-742dbc57cca9 which excluding the - would be 5 matching characters. would there be a faster way that just simply looping through every single character?

Comment: You seem to be interested in a variation of [the levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance). It might be a good idea to see [how that's implemented](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Levenshtein_distance#Java) and adapt it to your needs.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that both strings have the same length, this is as good as it gets:

```
public static int numberMatchingChars(String s1, String s2) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++)
        if (s1.charAt(i) == s2.charAt(i) && s1.charAt(i) != '-')
            count++;
    return count;
}
```

Clearly, you'll have to iterate over each char on both strings.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this would improve matters or not and assuming that both strings have the same length and format, but anyway, technically you do not need to visit every char.

```
String arr1[] = s1.split ("-");
String arr2[] = s2.split ("-");

int totCount = 0;

for (int x = 0; x < arr1.length; x++) {

   if (arr1[x].equals (arr2[x]) == false) {

       // compare char by char for arr1[x] to arr2[x]
       totCount += numberMatchingChars(arr1[x], arr2[x]);

   }
}

public static int numberMatchingChars(String s1, String s2) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++)
        if (s1.charAt(i) == s2.charAt(i))
            count++;
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Well, _technically_ this solution isn't visiting all chars _in the counting part_ (it's excluding `-`). But it makes three passes over the input strings, the `split()` operation comes with a cost (so yes, it's visiting all chars after all). It won't be faster than my original answer.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez I fully agree with you, and would never implement this myself - maybe I should have made that disclaimer.